# How to generate tflite from saved model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I want to create an object-detection app based on a retrained ssd_mobilenet model I've retrained like the guy on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku).

I chose the model `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco` from the [Tensorflow Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). After the retraining process I've got the model with the following structure:

```
- saved_model
    - variables (empty folder)
    - saved_model.pb
- checkpoint
- frozen_inverence_graph.pb
- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.meta
- pipeline.config
```

In the same folder, I have the python script with the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("saved_model", input_shapes={"image_tensor":[1,300,300,3]})
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

After running this code, I got the following error:

```
...
2019-05-24 18:46:59.811289: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1324] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-05-24 18:46:59.811864: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1373] Unable to determine output type for op: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-05-24 18:46:59.908207: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 1792 operators, 3033 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-24 18:47:00.089034: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 1771 operators, 2979 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-24 18:47:00.314681: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 1771 operators, 2979 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-05-24 18:47:00.453570: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/resolve_constant_slice.cc:59] Check failed: dim_size >= 1 (0 vs. 1)
```

Is there any solution for the "Check failed: dim_size >= 1 (0 vs. 1)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of MobileNet SSD is a little different due to some Custom ops that are needed in the graph.

Take a look at this [Medium post](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193) for the end-to-end process of training and exporting the model as a TFLite graph. For conversion, you would need to use the [export_tflite_ssd_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py) script.

Comment: It seems that '--add_postprocessing_op=true' solves this problem